# MVC Partials vs User Controls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to understand what the equivalent of a user control is within an MVC application? From what I understand, it's a Partial. The problem I'm finding is that when I use a user control, I'm able to encapsulate the logic within that control and re-use it across multiple pages without having to worry about the parent page.

How does this work with MVC? There doesn't seem to be any way to encapsulate logic with a partial view.. in fact it's confusing the hell out of me.

Does this mean that for any page that might use the partial, the controller would always have to return the data for the partial just in case it's required? Doesn't this seem incredibly inefficient? I can't seem to wrap my head around how this works...

Comment: That's exactly the same as having a aspx-page with a usercontrol inside. It will be loaded everytime to. For just loading the partial you would have a controller method returning only the partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add logic using razor syntax. For example, you can use conditional statements to manipulate the final output.

```
@{ 
    if(whatever == true) 
    {
       <p>Whatever is true</p>
    }
    else
    {
       <span id="someId">
           <label for="enterName">Enter name:</label> <input type="text" id="enterName" />
       </span>
    }
}
```

In addition to this you can use @helper syntax like

```
@helper MakeLink(dynamic id)
{
    <div id="actionButtons">
        @Html.ActionLink("Some Title", "Some Action", new {id = id}) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Another Title", "Another Action", "Some Controller", new {id = id})
    </div>
}
```

The logic in partials is slightly different to what you are used to in Web Forms user controls. The above logic can be placed in a Partial so that you can reuse it later, you just need to place it in /Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates or EditorTemplates.

Comment: I understand that razor can be used for simple logic but what if it wa something more complex? I suppose the hardest thing for me to understand is how you'd encapsulate logic with the partial view? Is this even possible?

Comment: How complex is the logic? If it is something overly complex you might want to rethink your strategy and create helper or utility classes that you could call from within partial to help you build the output.

Comment: Well for example, I was on a site that had to call on a number of web services, manipulate this returned data and then render it. This all worked fine for my user control as I could encapsulate all the logic.. but how would I do this in MVC?

Comment: You would call the web service from some action in your controller and pass the data as model to your Partial. Inside the partial process the model result.

Comment: Aha I suppose this is where the confusion lies - I'm assuming there's no way to encapsulate a partial controller somehow with a partial view? It's difficult to wrap my head around :-)

Comment: You are not really going to wrap controller around. You will just build a partial view that consumes certain type of model that any action from any controller, which needs partial view's service, will pass the data and receive rendered result. It is actually very easy to understand in practice.